# Why not updated width of this element? JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this page:

[link](http://bagel.dg-site.com/bagel/)

**CODE JS:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var windowsize = $(window).outerWidth();   
    var stanga= jQuery('#secondary').outerWidth();
    var dreapta= jQuery('.right').outerWidth();
    var contentwh=windowsize-stanga-dreapta;
    $('#main-content').css('width',contentwh); 
});
```

I am tried everything here works the same in the resize function.

```
$(window).on('resize',function(){
var contentwh=windowsize-stanga-dreapta;
console.log('laatime content:',contentwh);
$('#main-content').css('width',contentwh);
});
```

unfortunately not updated width ... remains the same as at first, it should change when resize the window.

Can you tell me please what is the problem and why this code does not work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't defined `windowsize`, `stanga`, or `dreapta` in the resize function.

They weren't globals to start with and even if they were, they would still have their old (pre-resize) values.

Comment: The one thing I might add to the answer is demonstrating to the OP how to properly update/retrieve the widths so they are not always using the _pre-resize_ values.

Comment: @hungerstar — They already have the code to do that in the question. It just needs putting in the right place.

Comment: I realize that. I was thinking the OP might need a _*nudge*_ as far as where to place it. No biggie.

Answer (score 0):

The sizes do not magically get updated when the page changes. You need to manually check the widths again.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(window).on("resize", function () {
        var windowsize = $(window).outerWidth(),   
            stanga= jQuery('#secondary').outerWidth(),
            dreapta = jQuery('.right').outerWidth(),
            contentwh = windowsize - stanga - dreapta;
        $('#main-content').css('width', contentwh);
    }).trigger("resize");
});
```

And there is no need to repeat the functionality multiple times, just call trigger on resize.